# Android Studio UNEXPECTED_TOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle, dependencies

I have reviewed several questions on here already regarding this matter but none are similar enough to my problem.

I am using the Wahoo Fitness Android API to get data from a heart rate monitor, this API depends on the main project having libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar as a dependency which is fine until an App Engine backend module is added to the project. My dependencies from the build.gradle file below from module app.

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/androidapi.jar')
compile files('libs/jEN.jar')
compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
//compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
```

}

And this is the error message which is shown when compiling/building.

```
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
:app:dexDebug
:app:preDexDebug
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

I am assuming that they are depending on the support library or something along those lines with different version numbers or there are duplication's of a dependency. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Multiple dependencies are trying to import same library... check your libraries, and when you find you can Except that library on build.gradle

Comment: It would seem this has solved the issue...
adding this to the build.gradle. as I could not find any duplicate dependencies!
android {
    ...
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

}

Comment: i have same issue please suggest me some sollution

Comment: The error for me was that one of my dependency libraries was depending on another library that the project was depending on so two of the same libraries but with different version numbers, thus causing the duplicate dependencies exception. I recommend systematically removing each dependency to identify which one is causing the problem. Also don't include whole folders of libraries, add them individually.